# ContextErrorException: Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

well I know that a lot of people ask for this error, but I tried to find my mistake and I can't.

First, I'm using FOSUSERBUNDLE for manage my users. I need managed three different user so I extends the main entity user from fosuserbundle and I created 3 more entities which have a field whit a reference to my user entity. Until this work fine.

Now, I have an entity called SolicituIngreso.php which is alter for this 3 different users. I show you the entities below:

```
class Usuario extends BaseUser
{
 /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
 protected $id;

 public function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct();

}
/** @ORM\column(type="string", length=255,nullable=true) 
*
*@Assert\NotBlank(message="Por favor ingrese su nombre.")
*@Assert\Length(
 *     min=1,
 *     max=255,
 *     minMessage="El nombre es demasiado corto.",
 *     maxMessage="El nombre es demasiado largo.")
**/
protected $nombre;

/** @ORM\column(type="string", length=255,nullable=true) 
*
*@Assert\NotBlank(message="Por favor ingrese su apellido.")
** @Assert\Length(
 *     min=1,
 *     max=255,
 *     minMessage="El nombre es demasiado corto.",
 *     maxMessage="El nombre es demasiado largo.")
**/
protected $apellido;
 ...
```

An example for one of my entities references to my Usuario.php:

```
class EncargadoBodega
{
    /** 
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GestionResiduos\UsuarioBundle\Entity\Usuario", cascade={"all"}, inversedBy="encargadoBodega")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="encargadoBodega_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    protected $encargadoBodega;
```

and another fields whith getters and setters.

Finally this is my entity SolicitudIngreso.php:

```
class SolicitudIngreso
{
    /**
    *@ORM\Id
    *@ORM\column(type="integer")
    *@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $numeroSolicitud;
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GestionResiduos\ResiduoBundle\Entity\Bodega", cascade={"all"}, inversedBy="solicitudesIngreso")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bodegaAsociadaIngreso_id", referencedColumnName="idBodega") 
    */  
    protected $bodegaAsociadaIngreso;
   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GestionResiduos\UsuarioBundle\Entity\OperarioBodega", cascade={"all"}, inversedBy="solicitudesIngresoOpB")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="operarioBodega_id", referencedColumnName="userOperarioBodega_id") 
    */        
    protected $operarioBodega;

/**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GestionResiduos\UsuarioBundle\Entity\OperarioGenerador", cascade={"all"}, inversedBy="solicitudesIngresoOpG")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="operarioGenerador_id", referencedColumnName="userGenerador_id") 
    */     
    protected $operarioGenerador;

/**
    * @ORM\column(type="text", nullable=true) 
    */      
    protected $obsEncargadoBodega;
```

I have another fields in this entity but I think if I solve for one entity I could do another entities.

BTW, in my controller I show you only the two method whit I have problems:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function crearSolicitudIngresoAction(Request $request)
    {
        $solicitudIngreso = new SolicitudIngreso();
        $ingresoResiduo= new IngresoResiduo();
        $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $temp = $userManager->findUserByUsername($this->getUser());
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $numeroOperario= $temp->getId();
        $operarioGenerador= $em->getRepository('UsuarioBundle:OperarioGenerador')->findOperarioGenerador($numeroOperario);
        $formulario = $this->createForm(new IngresoResiduoType(), $ingresoResiduo);
        $dateTime = new \DateTime();
        $residuos = $em->getRepository('ResiduoBundle:Residuo')->findResiduoCampos();
        $formulario->handleRequest($request);
        if($formulario->isValid())
        {
            $bandera=$solicitudIngreso->getEstadoSolicitud();
            if(($bandera != ""))
            {
             return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('solicitud_ingreso_pendientes_opg'));
         }
            $solicitudIngreso->setEstadoSolicitud("AOR"); //ADD OTRO RESIDUO
            $solicitudIngreso->setFechaSolicitud($dateTime);
            $solicitudIngreso->setObsOperarioGenerador($formulario->get('numeroSolicitud')['obsOperarioGenerador']->getData());
            $solicitudIngreso->setDepartamentoGenerador($formulario->get('numeroSolicitud')['departamentoGenerador']->getData());

            $formulario->get('numeroSolicitud')['obsOperarioGenerador']->getData();
            $em->persist($solicitudIngreso);
            //$solicitudIngreso->setEstadoSolicitud("AOR"); //Espera Aprobación Ingreso
            $em->flush();
            $numeroSolicitud = $solicitudIngreso->getNumeroSolicitud();
            $ingresoResiduo->setNumeroSolicitud($solicitudIngreso);
            $em->persist($ingresoResiduo);
            $em->flush();
            if ($operarioGenerador) {
                $solicitudIngreso->setOperarioGenerador($operarioGenerador);    
                $em->persist($solicitudIngreso);
                $em->flush();
            }
            /**********new code for manage more than one residuo**************/
            if ($formulario->get('addotro')->isClicked()){//acá meto un render y le paso la variable con el residuo a ingresar.
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(
                    'add_residuo_solicitud', array(
                        'idsolicitud' => $numeroSolicitud
                        )));
            } 
            $solicitudIngreso->setEstadoSolicitud("EAI"); //Espera Aprobación Ingreso
            $em->persist($solicitudIngreso);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(
                'detalle_pendiente_opg', array(
                    'id' => $numeroSolicitud
                    )));
        }
        return $this->render('SolicitudIngresoBundle:Default:crearSolicitudIngreso.html.twig', array(
            'formulario' => $formulario->createView(),
            'residuos' => $residuos
            ));
    }

public function addResiduoIngresoSolicitudIngresoAction(Request $request, $idsolicitud){
        $numeroSolicitud =$idsolicitud;
        $ingresoResiduo= new IngresoResiduo();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $formulario = $this->createForm(new AddNuevoResiduoType(), $ingresoResiduo);
        $formulario->handleRequest($request);
        if($formulario->isValid())
        {
            $solicitudIngreso=$em->getRepository('SolicitudIngresoBundle:SolicitudIngreso')->findSolicitudIngreso($numeroSolicitud);
            $ingresoResiduo->setNumeroSolicitud($solicitudIngreso);
            $em->persist($ingresoResiduo);
            $em->flush();
            if ($formulario->get('addotro')->isClicked()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(
                    'add_residuo_solicitud', array(
                        'idsolicitud' => $numeroSolicitud
                        )));
            }
            $em->persist($solicitudIngreso);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(
                'detalle_pendiente_opg', array(
                    'id' => $numeroSolicitud
                    )));
        }
        $residuosAdd= $em->getRepository('SolicitudIngresoBundle:IngresoResiduo')->findIngresoResiduos($idsolicitud);
        $residuos = $em->getRepository('ResiduoBundle:Residuo')->findResiduoCampos();
        return $this->render('SolicitudIngresoBundle:Default:addResiduoSolicitudIngreso.html.twig', array(
            'formulario' => $formulario->createView(),
            'residuosincluidos' => $residuosAdd,
            'id' => $idsolicitud,
            'residuos' => $residuos
            ));
    }
```

I am using a form for alter entity solicitudIngreso.php.

The problem is trowing when I try to persist with the function

> addResiduoIngresoSolicitudIngresoAction

and trowing the next error:

> ContextErrorException: Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gestionresiduospel\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line 1602

I think if I add my form could be help for you: [image]  In this case, I ve called the addotro and this form is **AddNuevoResiduoType**. So when I called button addotro again or try button crear Trowing the error.

I guess this could be cause my 3 entities that references to Usuario entity. But I can't solve the error. I really hope you can help me guys.

Comment: All that code and you didn't supply the line of code which is calling spl_object_hash.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think you need to take a look at what happens in the function `addResiduoIngresoSolicitudIngresoAction`

at this line

```
$solicitudIngreso=$em->getRepository('SolicitudIngresoBundle:SolicitudIngreso')->findSolicitudIngreso($numeroSolicitud);
```

I am not sure what happens in the repository function but you might be returning a string where the object `IngresoResiduo` expects to be an integer and trying to persist it.

Or this variable could be a string `$numeroSolicitud =$idsolicitud;` and then later be set to a property that doctrine expects to be an integer.

You could avoid some of this by adding validation. You could also try to make your method names and variables shorter or move some of the logic to a service to make the code more readable. It takes a bit longer to go through it.

Hope my suggestion helped. Let me know if you solved the issue!

Comment: Thank you for your advices. So in fact my variable $numeroSolicitud was getting a string. Now I getting an integer. In other hand, my called to repository effectively return an object( I printed a gettype)  but I always getting same error. Besides I was validating my form AddNuevoResiduoType and this is getting the right types and data. I am searching in my entities that associated with my IngresoResiduo Entity. I tell you if I find my mistake, thank a lot.

Comment: Solved, if you have another things that probably I forget or I don't considered you can tell me. Thank you bro.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my issue. Well I check my entities and found that in my entity solicitudIngreso I'm checking with a cascade validation for fields operarioBodega y operarioGenerador, so I deleted this check and all works fine. So I think that is because when I ask for the getId() to get my id for my operariogenerador I was getting a string cause is fosuserbundle that work with integer but my operariogenerador prints the username. I hope this could be work for another people that have this problem. Chao